# Dialogflow Agent regex entities definition

Tags: dialogflow-es

I have created an agent in dialogflow, for which I want to define an entity based on regex values, I know we have regex capability in defining the entities, but I don't know how to use it or how to define regex while defining the entity. There are no examples or blogs available to help me with this. I want to see an example or syntax of how to define regex entities so that I can replicate the same for my case. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.  Go to the Entity page.  Create a new Entity an call it whatever you want.  In the entity screen select regex and enter this value [A-Za-z]{3}[0-9]{7,10}$. Save the Entity. This regex will validate any value that begins with three letters and 7 to 10 character.  Example PAP1234567 or DWL123456789.

Now go to an, intent or create one, and on the training phrases add one that says:
My number is PAP12345678.  Select the PAP12345678 to highlighted and the entities menu will appeared.  Select the new regex entity and save.

Test the intent on DialogFlow.  Hope this help.